# UICollectionView overlaps with status bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I made a storyboard with a Collection View Controller as its initial view controller. However, when I insert a cell the status bar with the battery overlaps with it. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: xcode]

Does anyone know how to make it so the view controller starts underneath the status bar?

Comment: You need to setup constraints properly.

Comment: I can't seem to drag the collection view, see here: http://imgur.com/a/5s0ek

Comment: I still think this is a constraints issue. Look at this document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html)

@MarksCode

Answer (score 0):

I used the same approach with `CollectionViewController`, and it is giving me correct results:

[image]

Here is my storyboard screenshot:

[image]

Can you please show me your code so I can help you with the problem.

Also, this kind of problem arise when we drag and drop a `CollectionView` into our `ViewController`. In that case we need to explicitly set the constraints so that the `CollectionView` does not overlap the `status bar`.

In that case you need to set the `top constraint` of `CollectionView` to `ViewController's` `top margin`. **This will work in both cases when the status bar is hidden and when status bar is not hidden**. `Top margin` is set accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach you may take that at first take a view controller and then embedded it in a navigation controller. So you will be able to see proper navigation bar,height etc.

Then you take a collection view and Hook it and set proper constraint. Hope it takes some times but will do finely.

Comment: OP said nothing about wanting a navigation bar.

Comment: I just said one approach and @OP can hide easily navigation bar.